# laravel 6. ActiveCount of sub relationship of sub relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am building system with 3 models ( Nation, Minister , Officer ).

1. Nation has many Minister ;
2. Each Minister has many Officer

Model : Nation

```
function ministers(){
    return $this->hasMany( Minister::class );
}
```

Model : Minister

```
function officers(){
    return $this->hasMany( Officer::class );
}


function officersActiveCount(){
    return $this->hasMany( Officer::class)->where('state', 'active' )->count();
}
```

The following is workng ok . It gets all officers with corresponding ministers .

```
$nation = Nation::where('id', $nation_id)->with('ministers.officers')->get();
```

But I want to get 'ministers' and 'officersActiveCount' NOT 'officers'

How can I get the officersActiveCount with each nations ?

...

Answer (score 0):

Change the relationship on the **Minister** model and remove the count.  That count in the relationship will screw up the eager loading.  So:

```
function active(){
   return $this->hasMany( Officer::class)->where('state', 'active' );
}
```

Now you can use a closure on the `with()` method and pull that secondary relationship and get the count using the [Larvel method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount()`.

Something like this:

```
 $nation = Nation::where('id', $nation_id)->with(['ministers' => function($query){
        $query->withCount('active');
    }])->get();
```

It should be eager loaded and you can access the active count via the `$nation` object and its relation, `ministers`:

```
 $activeOfficers = $nation->ministers->first()->active_count;
```

This will give you the active officers for the first minister for that nation.  If you want to total all of them, easy to loop:

```
$totalActiveOfficersForNation = 0;
foreach($nation->ministers as $minister){
    $totalActiveOfficersForNation += $minister->active_count;
}
```

There are other ways to count columns, but this is pretty straightforward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any message with that failure or did the computer just start smoking?  ;)

Comment: 'Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer'  error message shows.   I wonder how to represent officersActiveCount as object .. it should not be mixed with minister Object.

Comment: Thanks for your corcern. I am not good at mordern way ... sorry for that.

Comment: Heh - me either - no worries.  Give that a try.  Might have to tweak a little to get it working.  I also changed the model relationship name to make it easier to understand.